# ¿Cómo resolver ecuaciones que han sido introducidas mediante simpify?

Tags: python, sympy

Estoy realizando este codigo en Python:

```
import sympy as sp

def TransformarAEcuaciones(Matriz_Entrada):
    Matriz_Split = []
    Matriz_Ecuaciones = []
    for Ecuacion in range(len(Matriz_Entrada)):
        Matriz_Split = Matriz_Entrada[Ecuacion].split("=")
        for Expresion in range(len(Matriz_Split)):
            if Expresion == 0:
                Lado_Izquierdo = sp.sympify(Matriz_Split[Expresion])
            if Expresion != 0:
                Lado_Derecho = sp.sympify(Matriz_Split[Expresion])
        Ecuacion_Obtenida = sp.Eq(Lado_Izquierdo,Lado_Derecho)
        Matriz_Ecuaciones.append(Ecuacion_Obtenida)
    return Matriz_Ecuaciones

Matriz_Ecuaciones_Str = ["a=b*c"] 
Matriz_Ecuaciones_Sympy = TransformarAEcuaciones(Matriz_Ecuaciones_Str)
print(Matriz_Ecuaciones_Str)
print(Matriz_Ecuaciones_Sympy)

for i in range(len(Matriz_Ecuaciones_Sympy)):
    print("Si resolvemos para b")
    PruebaText = sp.solve(Matriz_Ecuaciones_Sympy[i],b)
    print(PruebaText)
```

Pero no logro que resuelva la ecuación ya declarada

Entiendo que ahí el error seria que "b" no esta definida como Symbol previamente, pero ya probé definiéndola antes (junto con "a" y "c"), no indica un error, pero tampoco obtiene la solución de b.

Analice por separado todos los elementos de la ecuación, para saber si correspondían al tipo adecuado, y si la ecuación Matriz_Ecuaciones_Sympy[i] aparece como tipo <class 'sympy.core.relational.Equality'> lo cual es correcto, y las letras que la conforman "a", "b" o "c" aparecen como tipo <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>, también correctas, entonces no se donde esta el problema o por que no me puede dar la solución con solve.

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la solución más simple es pasar la varible para la cual quieres resolver como cadena (o sea, `"b"` en lugar de `b`). Ya `sympy` se encarga de interpretarla correctamente como símbolo. Mira este código de ejemplo:

```
# No es necesario tocar la definición de TrasnformarAEcuaciones
# de modo que no la incluyo por brevedad

# Probamos con un par de ecuaciones
Matriz_Ecuaciones_Str = ["a=b*c", "a+b=0"] 
Matriz_Ecuaciones_Sympy = TransformarAEcuaciones(Matriz_Ecuaciones_Str)
print(Matriz_Ecuaciones_Str)

for i in range(len(Matriz_Ecuaciones_Sympy)):
    PruebaText = sp.solve(Matriz_Ecuaciones_Sympy[i],"b")
    print("b =", PruebaText)
```

Resultado:

```
['a=b*c', 'a+b=0']
b = [a/c]
b = [-a]
```

También funciona definir previamente `b` como símbolo. No sé qué habrías hecho para que no te funcione, pero bastaba poner `b = sp.Symbol("b")` antes del bucle `for`.

Comment: Ya quedo todo funcionando, respecto a lo de definir previamente las variables lo probé una vez mas y esta vez si funciono, no tengo idea de que paso antes, quizá era un error en mi Visual, pero en fin Gracias